# Z-index not working on :before & :after

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to make a ribbon like the one in the image linked, but when I use z-index to send the edges behind the main part of the ribbon it disappears completely behind the pages background color. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code?[ribbon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExXDv.png)

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Newsletter signup</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class = "header">
            <h1 class = "logo">skillcrush</h1>
              <div class="ribbon">
                <p>the delightful way to learn</p>
              </div>
           </div><!--header-->
        </div><!--container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.container-body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:1200px;
  height:702px;
  background-color:#fff0da;
  z-index: auto;
}

.ribbon{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size:16px;
  background-color:#f6515d;
  height:28px;
  width:260px;
  color:rgb(255, 240, 218);
  border: solid #fff0da 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ribbon:before
{
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  border-width: 20px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f6515d #f6515d #f6515d transparent;
  z-index: 1;


}
.ribbon:after
{
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  right:-30px;
  top: -10px;
  border-width: 20px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f6515d transparent #f6515d #f6515d;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You need to establish a new stacking context on the `.container-body`.

```
.container-body { z-index: 1; position: relative; /* ... */ }
```

Then use negative z-indexing on the pseudo-elements:

```
.ribbon { /* no z-index, ... */ }
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after { z-index: -1; /* ... */ }
```

Here is a full example:

```css
.container-body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:1200px;
  height:702px;
  background-color:#fff0da;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size:16px;
  background-color:#f6515d;
  height:28px;
  width:260px;
  color:rgb(255, 240, 218);
  border: solid #fff0da 2px;
}

.ribbon:before
{
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  border-width: 20px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f6515d #f6515d #f6515d transparent;
  z-index: -1;


}
.ribbon:after
{
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  right:-30px;
  top: -10px;
  border-width: 20px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f6515d transparent #f6515d #f6515d;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-body">
  <div class="ribbon">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have also to set `relative` as *position* for the pseudo-element.